# Invalid column name error when creating a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a stored procedure but am getting these errors:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert_QuickLabDump, Line 42
Invalid column name 'Date_Collected'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert_QuickLabDump, Line 43
Invalid column name 'Time_Collected'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert_QuickLabDump, Line 43
Invalid column name 'Date_Entered'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert_QuickLabDump, Line 44
Invalid column name 'Time_Entered'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert_QuickLabDump, Line 45
Invalid column name 'Date_Completed'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert_QuickLabDump, Line 46
Invalid column name 'Time_Completed'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert_QuickLabDump, Line 47
Invalid column name 'Test_Date'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert_QuickLabDump, Line 48
Invalid column name 'Test_Time'.
```

here is the full source:

```
USE [SalesDWH]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Insert_QuickLabDump]    Script Date: 12/22/2011 14:52:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_QuickLabDump]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Specimen_ID [varchar](50),
    @Client_Key int,
    @Outcome [varchar](50),
    @Medications [varchar] (max),
    @Date_Collected date,
@Time_Collected time ,
@Date_Entered date,
@Time_Entered time ,
@Date_Completed date,
@Time_Completed time ,
@Test_Date date ,
@Test_Time time ,

    @Practice_Name [varchar] (500),
    @Practice_Code [varchar] (500),
    @Client_ID [varchar] (500),
    @Requesting_Physician [varchar] (500),
    @Other_Medications [varchar] (max),
    @Order_Comments [varchar] (max),
    @Reference_Number [varchar] (500),
    @Order_Count int

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump]
           ([Specimen ID]
           ,[Client Key]
           ,[Outcome]
           ,[Medications]
           ,[Date_Collected]
           ,[Time_Collected]
           ,[Date_Entered]
           , [Time_Entered]
           , Date_Completed
           , Time_Completed
           , Test_Date
           , Test_Time
           ,[Practice Name]
           ,[Practice Code]
           ,[Client ID]
           ,[Requesting Physician]
           ,[Other Medications]
           ,[Order Comments]
           ,[Reference Number]
           ,[Order Count]
     )
     VALUES
           (@Specimen_ID,
@Client_Key,
@Outcome,
@Medications,
@Date_Collected ,
@Time_Collected ,
@Date_Entered,
@Time_Entered ,
@Date_Completed ,
@Time_Completed,
@Test_Date ,
@Test_Time,
@Practice_Name,
@Practice_Code,
@Client_ID,
@Requesting_Physician,
@Other_Medications,
@Order_Comments,
@Reference_Number,
@Order_Count
)


END
```

What am I doing wrong?

here is the table structure:

```
USE [SalesDWH]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[QuickLabDump]    Script Date: 12/22/2011 15:13:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuickLabDump](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Specimen ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Client Key] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Outcome] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Medications] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Date Collected] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Time Collected] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Date Entered] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Time Entered] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Date Completed] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Time Completed] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Test Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Test Time] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Practice Name] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Practice Code] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Client ID] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Requesting Physician] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Other Medications] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Order Comments] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Reference Number] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Order Count] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you added those columns to an existing procedure.  Have you added the columns to the database table you are trying to insert to?

Answer (score 9):

The errors are saying that there are no such columns (for example `Date_Collected`) in the `QuickLabDump` table.  For `insert` statements, you have to have the right column names.  You have a column named `Date Collected`, not `Date_Collected`, for example (note the space instead of the underscore).

Comment: happy hanukah. as you can see my create table shows that they exist

Comment: `[Date_Collected]` will not match `[Date Collected]`.

Comment: Happy Summer Solstice (from Down Under), but Jacob is right. Unless SQL Server has been enhanced massively in the last few years, it will not be able to magically figure out that `xyzzy_plugh` is the same as `xyzzy plugh` :-)

Comment: spaces in field names is just painful all around. either use _ or eliminate the space.

Answer (score 5):

You are using `[Date_Collected]` in your stored procedure, but the actual column name according to the `CREATE TABLE` statement is `[Date Collected]` (no underscore).

Answer (score 2):

[Date Collected] [date] NOT NULL, 
is not the same as Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert_QuickLabDump, Line 42 
Invalid column name 'Date_Collected'.